# Certain Windows Not Popping Up

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, window, upload

So I am new to Ubuntu 22.04.2, just switched over from Windows 10 earlier this year, and I've been having an issue lately.

I have no idea what I've done or what happened but for the past few weeks I've been having an issue where certain windows won't ever open no matter what I do.

One problem is whenever I'm using Firefox or Google Chrome, I'll right click on am image to save it, and then wait for several seconds without any windows popping up asking me where to save the image.

Secondly, my Discord will also not open up a window to allow me to upload pictures.

I'm not sure what I could have done to cause the problem. I'm mostly a PC gamer so most of the time I'm downloading games and adding whatever packages they need to me to add. The only thing I can think of that the instructions confused me on was my attempt at trying to get OpenRGB to work. I downloaded whatever packages they said I needed to but in the end I could never get the program to work so maybe one of them? But even so I really don't know how to uninstall specific packages, especially when there's a lot.

Comment: It could be possible this is related to packages if you've been making a lot of changes to your package manager. In the future, keep a record of what you're doing on your system in case it creates problems. It also helps to be conscious of what you're doing to your system. Can you post the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to your question? This will give us a good idea of the state of your package manager. Please copy/paste the whole output and use [code fences](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20164). Don't add info in comments. Tag me in a comment @nmath when finished.

Comment: Can you also link to any instructions you were following, especially if they could be related to the problem?

Comment: You can see which packages you have installed by looking at the files `/var/log/apt/*`, with tools like `less`, `more` and `grep`.

Comment: @Nmath Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.